# Exchange 2007 push notifications doesn't getting any events like new mail event

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using push notifications for new mail arriving But i can subscribed but i cannot get any events like new mail events which were subscribed.  please suggest me or help about this. if any other stuff to overcome I appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code how you create your subscription and how you get the Events?